# persist data to DynamoDB in Alexa hosted app

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Are there any really good articles breaking down how to persist data into DynamoDB from Alexa? I can't seem to find a good article to break down step by step on how to persist a slot value into DynamoDB. I see in the Alexa docs [here](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-session-persistence.html) about implementing the code in Python, but that seems to be only part of what I'm looking for.

There's really no comprehensive breakdown of this, as [like this tutorial](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-first-skill/tree/master/module-1), that persists data to S3. I would like to try to find something similar for DynamoDB. If there's an answer from a previous question that has answered it, let me know and I can mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a tutorial which uses python and aws lambdas.
Like this one:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.html
- the amazon article is more about the development kit which can give you some nice features to store persistent attributes for a users.
- so usually I have a persistent store for users (game scores, ..., last use of skill whatever) and additional data in an other table

Comment: Wow, easy enough. I guess I looked at it from the wrong angle. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The persistence adapter has an interface spec that abstracts away most of the details operationally. You should be able to change persistence adapters by initializing one that meets the spec, and in the initialization there may be some different configuration options. But the way you put things in and get them out should remain functionally the same.

You can find the configuration options for S3 and Dynamo here. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/manage-attributes.html

I have written a "local persistence adapter" in JavaScript to let me store values in flat files at localhost instead of on S3 when I'm doing local dev/debug. Swapping the two out (depending on environment) is all handled at adapter initialization. My handlers that use the attributes manager don't change.